# I would be happy if there was the ability to loop tasks in pipeline especially "for each" loop

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I would be happy if there was the ability to loop tasks in pipeline especially "for each" loop.

sometimes I have a task that I need to run a few time with different parameters.
this different parameters i take it from json file each block in json file give me different parameter
how i can build the tasks in azure with the number of block in json file with different parameter

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/each-expression.md ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way of creating `loop of tasks` naively in Azure DevOps UI.

If you want to achieve such a results I suggest to change you pipeline from `Visual/UI` to  [Yaml Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema). Than you can just use `each` expression. Otherwise, you should be write script block that will run you task in a loop or parallel.

You can be also interested in that post: [Looping Problem in Azure DevOps](https://mattvsts.github.io/2019/05/04/solving-the-looping-problem-in-Azure-DevOps-Pipelines/)

Comment: thank for your answer 
it work if you have template.yml and parse the Param from the azure_pipeline
but in my case i have file json and i need to loop on it as array by each in yml 
can you help me ?
like this in power Shell
$MyFile = (Get-Content -Path 'DataFile.json') -join "`n"  | ConvertFrom-Json
>> foreach ($i in $myfile.data) {
>> echo $i.nameicon
>> }